# Overlay closes before pop-up transitions sideways

Tags: html, css

My question is rather simple. I have a pop-up that slides open from right to left and expect it to slide close from left to right. Currently I am able to open the pop-up properly from but not able to slide it off the way I am expecting.

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="items-content">
         <h1> hello </h1>
    </div>
</div>

.overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s linear;
}

.overlay {
   &.-show {
      opacity: 1
   }
}

.overlay {
    .items-content {
         transform: translateX(200%);
         transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
     }
}

.overlay {
    &.-show {
       .items-content {
           transform: translateX(0);
           transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set the opacity, add transitions, transition delays but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset position, try below:

```
.overlay {
&.-show {
   .items-content {
       transform: translateX(0); //  this should be 0
       transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply but seems like I put 200% by mistake. That's how I currently have it in my code.